# What is XA Transactions ? How to Enable XA Transactions for SQL Server 2016 on Windows

Tags: sql-server, database-administration, msdtc, xa

- What are XA transactions?
- What are they used for?

I want to enable XA transactions for SQL Server 2016 on Windows. Do you know the steps to enable this?

Also is there any way to test if it is successfully enabled from the database side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find below the useful links which may help you.

What are XA transactions and its usage:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X/Open_XA
https://www.xenovation.com/blog/development/java/java-professional-developer/what-is-a-two-phase-commit-2pc-xa-transaction

Enable XA transactions for SQL Server
:
https://kb.informatica.com/howto/6/pages/20/513618.aspx

How to verify:
https://kb.informatica.com/supporttv/1/Pages/1/516401.aspx

Hope this helps you.